# Drop duplicates where two columns have same values - pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm aiming to drop duplicates values in a df. However, I want to drop where two values in separate columns are the same. Using below, I want to drop where `Value` and `Item` are duplicates. However, I want to keep the row where `['Group1'] == df['Group']`.

Note: `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Value', 'Item'])` will not always be ideal as it depends on the ordering in `Group`. For instance, duplicates found in `Item` `80.0` and `260.0`, the first row should be kept, but the second row should be kept for `Item` `310.0`. I don't want to sort values here either as the strings could change. For example the groups could be `Blue` and `Green`, which would alter the intended output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Value' : ['X','X','Y','Z','D','D','E','E','X'],    
    'Item' : [80.0,80.0,200.0,210.0,260.0,260.0,300.0,300.0,310.0],  
    'Group' : ['Red','Green','Red','Green','Red','Green','Green','Red','Green'],            
    'Group1' : ['Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red','Red'],       
    'Group2' : ['Green','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green'],                                  
    })

df = df[df['Group1'] == df['Group']].drop_duplicates(subset = ['Item','Value'])
```

If I perform `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Value', 'Item'])`, the output is:

```
  Value   Item  Group Group1 Group2
0     X   80.0    Red    Red  Green
2     Y  200.0    Red    Red  Green
3     Z  210.0  Green    Red  Green
4     D  260.0    Red    Red  Green
6     E  300.0  Green    Red  Green # incorrect
8     X  310.0  Green    Red  Green
```

intended output:

```
  Value   Item  Group Group1 Group2
0     X   80.0    Red    Red  Green
1     Y  200.0    Red    Red  Green
2     Z  210.0  Green    Red  Green
3     D  260.0    Red    Red  Green
4     E  300.0    Red    Red  Green
5     X  310.0  Green    Red  Green
```

Comment: I dont think your explanation is clear enough; besides ``df.drop_duplicates(['Value', 'Item'])`` seems to get your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy, more detail has been added.

Comment: @Chopin Does it mean that you need to keep a record with priority `Group==Group1` and then `Group!=Group1`

Comment: Looks like you are expecting `Red` as first record. Your dataset has `Green` as first record. If you want to swap, then sort the data by descending order. Then you will get `Red` first and `Green` second for `'Group'`. That will solve your problem. Alternate, provide additional details for us to help you

Comment: @JoeFerndz, I've added a note in the question explaining why this may not work long term. I've used dummy data and the strings will in `Group` will change. So sorting won't be ideal as I'll need to continually change it to ascending or descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Item','Value'])
df2 = df[df['Group'] == df['Group1']]
```

- Dataframe `df1` drop duplicates row on columns `Item` and `Value`.
- Dataframe `df2` keeps the rows where the value between column `Group` and column `Group1` is the same.

> I want to keep the row where ['Group1'] == df['Group'].

One left thing you need do is to replace values of dataframe `df1` with the values of dataframe `df2`, if their both `Item` and `Value` column values are the same.

[pandas.DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) can modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame. You can use it like:

```py
df1.set_index(['Value', 'Item'], inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index(['Value', 'Item']))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True) # to recover the initial structure
```

```
# print(df1)
  Value   Item  Group Group1 Group2
0     X   80.0    Red    Red  Green
1     Y  200.0    Red    Red  Green
2     Z  210.0  Green    Red  Green
3     D  260.0    Red    Red  Green
4     E  300.0    Red    Red  Green
5     X  310.0  Green    Red  Green
```

Besides `update`, you can use the index of the dataframe `df2` to slice `df1` and then assign.

```py
df1.set_index(['Value', 'Item'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Value', 'Item'], inplace=True)

df1.loc[df2.index] = df2

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.concat([df[df.Group == df.Group1],df[df.Group != df.Group1]]).drop_duplicates(subset = ['Item','Value']).sort_index()
```

Output

```
  Value   Item  Group Group1 Group2
0     X   80.0    Red    Red  Green
2     Y  200.0    Red    Red  Green
3     Z  210.0  Green    Red  Green
4     D  260.0    Red    Red  Green
7     E  300.0    Red    Red  Green
8     X  310.0  Green    Red  Green
```